# MVC SportsStore:[Building a Category Navigation Menu]

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been following Steven Sanderson's book called Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework, and I'm running into an exception:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during
>   the compilation of a resource required
>   to service this request. Please review
>   the following specific error details
>   and modify your source code
>   appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0121: The
>   call is ambiguous between the
>   following methods or properties:
>   'Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ViewExtensions.RenderAction(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   string, string)' and
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   string, string)'

```
Line 15:     </div>
Line 16:     <div id="catagories">
Line 17:         <% Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); %>
Line 18:     </div>
Line 19:     <div id="content">
```

My Site.Master code:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="title">
            SPORT STORE</div>
    </div>
    <div id="catagories">
        <% Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); %>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
    </div>
</body>
```

I thank I Know where is wrong. When I change Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll of MVC1 to Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll of MVC2, this error is solved. But it appear other error:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during
>   the compilation of a resource required
>   to service this request. Please review
>   the following specific error details
>   and modify your source code
>   appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The
>   type or namespace name 'NavLink' does
>   not exist in the namespace
>   'WebUI.Controllers' (are you missing
>   an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
Line 170:    
Line 171:    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGlobalScopeAttribute()]
Line 172:    public class views_nav_menu_ascx : System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<WebUI.Controllers.NavLink>> {
Line 173:        
Line 174:        private static bool @__initialized;
```

So, How can I do now?

Answer (score 1):

On Chapter 5, Page 137:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl
<IEnumerable<WebUI.Controllers.NavLink>>" %>
```

Didn't work for me. I kept getting: The type or namespace name 'NavLink' does not exist in the namespace 'WebUI.Controllers'

I had to change "... Controllers.NavLink..." to "... Controllers.NavController.NavLink..." in order for it to work. Like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl
<IEnumerable<WebUI.Controllers.NavController.NavLink>>" %>
```